# unable to connect to the jdbc:derby://Localehost:1527/test using org.apache.derby

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

[Hi everyone , i have error while developing web application using jsp and servlet and , i have captured the screen shot below please find out the error image while connecting to the jdbc.derby, iam using netdbeans 8.0.2 in windows 10 .

Thanks in advance if anyone has solution for it  [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRo4u.png)

Comment: the link is broken. pls fix it

Comment: Is that a typo in the title? localehost is not the same as localhost. That might already be your problem (cannot see the screenshot since your link is broken)

Comment: here is the screen shot http://i.stack.imgur.com/vRo4u.png

Comment: And output i got during the connection :-Wed Mar 16 19:16:28 IST 2016 : Security manager installed using the Basic server security policy.
Wed Mar 16 19:16:28 IST 2016 : Could not listen on port 1527 on host localhost:
 java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

Comment: Run this command in console to see what's using your port: `netstat -anob`

Comment: Is the database name a typo? Should it be "OnlineTest" instead of "OnlineTestt" ? If not then you can create the database when connecting by adding `create=true` to the URL.